# Проблема с Cordova plugin googlemaps: NoApiKeys

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova

Использую данный плагин [cordova-plugin-googlemaps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps)

Подключаю по инструкции в config.xml прописываю:

```
<widget ...>
 <preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY" value="(api key)" />
 <preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_IOS_API_KEY" value="(api key)" />
</widget>
```

но получаю такое:
[image: google maps]

и предупреждение в консоли:

> Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Кто сталкивался с подобным?
То, что мог нагуглить - не помогает.

P.S. Так же пробовал использовать совместно с Framework7 - та же история.